# Making Textarea and submit button in .php to hide for every row in database table?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

Been working on  this for long time.. want to add a js effect (hide/unhide) to a simple submit form...

Fortunately it is working but unfortunately it is only working for single row in the DB table.

I made script:1 (posted below) which was corrected by a well wisher from this site which is script:2 (posted below).

unfortunately both are not working. hope you guys help me find the missing peice in it..

SCRIPT#1

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$password = "*****";
 $dbname = "the_database";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM input";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
?>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/normalize.css" />
<style>
.name {
width: 700px;
margin-top: 1%;
margin-left: 20%;
padding-left:2%;
padding-right:2%;
padding-top:10%;
margin-right: 35%;
word-wrap: break-word;
}
textarea#addtext{
width:600px;
height:100px;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.js">
</script>
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
$(window).load(function(){
$().ready = function() {
 $('#addtext').hide();
$('#addsubmit').hide();
$("#add").click(function() {
$('#add').hide();
$('#addtext').fadeIn('slow').focus();
$('#addsubmit').fadeIn('slow');
});

$('#addtext').blur(function(){
    $('#addtext').hide();
    $('#addsubmit').hide();
    $('#add').fadeIn('slow');    
});
}();
});//]]>

</script>

</head>
<body>

                        <div class="name">

                                <?php 
                            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { ?>

                        <div id="q">
                            <B><big><font color= #ba4a00> Q:</font></big> <?php echo $row["question"]; ?> </B></br>
                            <B><small><font color= #ba4a00> Description:</font> <?php echo $row["description"]; ?>  </small></B></br>
                            <p id="tag1"><small> <?php echo $row["subject"]; ?> </small></p><p id="tag2"><small> <?php echo $row["sub_subject"]; ?> </small></p>
                            <button class="addanswer" id="add"><B>Add Answer</B></button>
                        <form>
                        <textarea class="addtext" name="addtext" required id="addtext" placeholder="Please type your question here.."></textarea>
                        <button class="addanswer" id="addsubmit"><B>Submit</B></button>
                        </form>
                            <small><p><?php echo $row["date"]; ?></p></small>
                                                    </div>                                                  
                            <?php     }
                                } else {
                                    echo "0 results";
                                        }
                                $conn->close();
                            ?>
                        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

SCRIPT#2

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "******";
$dbname = "the_database";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM input";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
?>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/normalize.css" />
<style>
.name {
width: 700px;
margin-top: 1%;
margin-left: 20%;
padding-left:2%;
padding-right:2%;
padding-top:10%;
margin-right: 35%;
word-wrap: break-word;
}
textarea#addtext{
width:600px;
height:100px;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.js">
</script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
function addanswer(index){
 $('#add_' + index).hide();
$('#addtext_' + index).fadeIn('slow').focus();
$('#addsubmit_' + index).fadeIn('slow');
}
</script>

</head>
<body>

                        <div class="name">

                            <?php 
                            if ($result->num_rows > 0) { 
                            $index = 0; 
                            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 
                            $index++; // stuff inside foreach goes here 
                            ?>

                        <div id="q">
                            <B><big><font color= #ba4a00> Q:</font></big> <?php echo $row["question"]; ?> </B></br>
                            <B><small><font color= #ba4a00> Description:</font> <?php echo $row["description"]; ?>  </small></B></br>
                            <p id="tag1"><small> <?php echo $row["subject"]; ?> </small></p><p id="tag2"><small> <?php echo $row["sub_subject"]; ?> </small></p>
                        <?php 
                            echo '<button class="add" id="add_'.$index.'"><B>Add</B></button>';
                            echo '<form style="display:none;" name="answer_'.$index.'" method="post" action="output.php">'; // I dont think openning form from row to row would be nice!
                            echo '<textarea style="display:none;"  type="text" class="addtext" name="addtext" required id="addtext_'.$index.'" placeholder="Please type your question here.."></textarea>';
                            echo '<button style="display:none;" onClick="addsubmit('.$index.');" type="addsubmit" id="addsubmit_'.$index.'" class="addsubmit"><B>Submit</B></button>';
                            echo '</form>';
                        ?>
                            <small><p><?php echo $row["date"]; ?></p></small>
                        </div>                                                  
                            <?php     }
                                } else {
                                    echo "0 results";
                                        }
                                $conn->close();
                            ?>
                        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Any Help would be greatly Appreciated..

Comment: you have a syntax error here `</script>
</style>` you need to get rid of the `</style>` tag. Edit: Ok, you edited that out.

Comment: Plus, you shouldn't be putting PHP directives inside `<head>...</head>`. It's not good for markup.

Comment: Did that .... stil no hope..

Comment: I know my comments were not the solution, that's why I posted that as a comment to show you what markup syntax errors you had. You will need to elaborate in your question as to what is not working. "Not working" doesn't describe the issue, whether it be db errors, js errors, if you're checking for them. Did you look at your console? php/mysql error checking?

Comment: My apologies man. i didn't meant in that way... and yes, i did checked DB too.. everything is fine in this side..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so here is your code rewritten, I have not tested it but it should work if your PHP code has no syntax error and your DB is up and running:

`config.php` (I added config.php as its just better practice)

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "******";
$dbname = "the_database";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
?>
```

list.php (this will be your template file and some php logic in there *not the best practice)

```
<?php require_once('config.php') ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/normalize.css" />
    <style>
        .name {
            width: 700px;
            margin-top: 1%;
            margin-left: 20%;
            padding-left: 2%;
            padding-right: 2%;
            padding-top: 10%;
            margin-right: 35%;
            word-wrap: break-word;
        }

        textarea#addtext {
            width: 600px;
            height: 100px;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.js">
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="name">

        <?php 
                                $sql = "SELECT * FROM input";
                                $result = $conn->query($sql);

                                if ($result->num_rows > 0) { 
                                $index = 0; 
                                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 
                                $index++; // stuff inside foreach goes here 
                                ?>

        <div id="q">
            <!-- NEVER user an ID on elements that are recurring, thats completely wrong, use a class or 'data-' attr  -->
            <B><big><font color= #ba4a00> Q:</font></big> <?php echo $row["question"]; ?> </B>
            </br>
            <B><small><font color= #ba4a00> Description:</font> <?php echo $row["description"]; ?>  </small></B>
            </br>
            <p id="tag1"><small> <?php echo $row["subject"]; ?> </small></p>
            <p id="tag2"><small> <?php echo $row["sub_subject"]; ?> </small></p>
            <?php 
                                echo '<button class="add" id="add_'.$index.'"><B>Add</B></button>';
                                echo '<form style="display:none;" name="answer_'.$index.'" method="post" action="output.php">'; // I dont think openning form from row to row would be nice!
                                echo '<textarea  type="text" class="addtext" name="addtext" required id="addtext_'.$index.'" placeholder="Please type your question here.."></textarea>';
                                echo '<button onClick="addsubmit('.$index.');" type="submit" id="addsubmit_'.$index.'" class="addsubmit"><B>Submit</B></button>';
                                echo '</form>';
                            ?>
            <small><p><?php echo $row["date"]; ?></p></small>
        </div>
        <?php     }
                                    } else {
                                        echo "0 results";
                                            }
                                    $conn->close();
                                ?>
    </div>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.add').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).parent().find('form').fadeIn('slow').focus();
                $(this).hide();
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**Second Edit**

If you need to hide the form when the textarea is out of focus:
https://api.jquery.com/focusout/

```
$('.addtext').focusout(function() {
     $(this).parent().fadeOut('slow');
     $(this).parent().parent().find('.add').show();
});
```

** Third Edit **
Auto Focus on the textarea specifically

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.add').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).parent().find('form').fadeIn('slow');
                $(this).parent().find('form textarea.addtext').focus();
                $(this).hide();
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Brilliant.. and hey.. is there any way that i can get this hide function back when textarea gets focused out....

Comment: check my update... also PLEASE read my comments in your code, ID needs to be unique throughout the entire page.

Comment: thanks for the help. and another thing. the autofocus on  the text area is having the same issue of working only for once, after that it loses its focus until we click in it..

Comment: is it only working "ONCE" or for "ONE" item? from what I understood the autofocus is only applied when you click on a `$(".add")` button, after that you need to cancel/hide the form and then click on the "add" button again to recreate it!

Comment: yaa.... it is only working for once... working for all texareas but only once. then again i had to refresh the page again... its like when you click on "add" button textarea comes focused later you can hide it by clicking outside then again when you click on "add" button it wont come auto focused...

Comment: check 3rd edit... You should honestly try to read and understand my code as you could have easily done the last step by yourself.

Comment: I m sorry man.  Basically i m a working Chemical engineer and all of this so new to me..  So,  i guess it takes time..

Comment: @user6779766 no worries, I dont mean to be condescending or anything, I just want to make sure that you try and learn the basics as oppose to putting code snippets together to get a system up and running as you would not be able to maintain your own code if you just copy and paste code.

Comment: hey i ran into another problem again.. usually we gave the focus out function to addtext button but when irrespective of it even if i click on "addtext" button also it is executing the function without letting the button to be clicked. so it is like hiding the texarea with your text in it without submitting it.

Comment: can you show me a demo page? its hard to debug the behaviour without seeing what is happening

Comment: mate you are killing me :) here is a demo page: https://jsfiddle.net/u5uzgmpu/   if I understand your problem correctly then you need to remove focusout function from the textarea and add it to the right element on the page (either the form, or place a cancel button) ... the code is behaving the way you asked for it so you need to make some minor adjustments to get the result you need.

Comment: i just gone through the link... and it exactl the same. there isn't much change in it. even in that jsfiddle output also the submit button is behaving the same... can we do anything about it..?

Comment: the link was a demo page :) I didnt change anything tbh because I didnt know what exactly you want.... here is the updated version: https://jsfiddle.net/u5uzgmpu/3/     I am not sure if its gonna be exactly what you want but you should be able to customize that further to get exactly what you want... what I did was setup a click event on window and if its not triggered on the "form" object then it will hide it, otherwise it will keep it open

Comment: Can you take a look on this one man... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39330887/slide-up-slide-down-is-not-working-for-selected-table-rows-from-db